# pyschools Topic 3 Q 6

Tags: python

I'm trying to solve this question:

http://www.pyschools.com/quiz/view_question/s3-q6

> ### Write a function using 'if/elif/else' conditionals to compute the BMI of a person, and return the risk associated with cardiovascular diseases.
>
> BMI = weight(kg)/( height(m)*height(m) )
>
> BMI    Risk
>
> 27.5 and above High Risk
>
> 23 - 27.4   Moderate Risk
>
> 18.5 - 22.9     Low Risk
>
> Below 18.5  Risk of nutritional deficiency diseases
>
> Examples
>
> HealthScreen(85, 1.75)
>
> 'Your BMI is 27.8 (High Risk).'
>
> HealthScreen(68, 1.65)
>
> 'Your BMI is 25.0 (Moderate Risk).'
>
> HealthScreen(60, 1.63)
>
> 'Your BMI is 22.6 (Low Risk).'
>
> HealthScreen(40,1.58)
>
> 'Your BMI is 16.0 (Risk of nutritional deficiency diseases).'

However I fail the Private Test Cases with this code

```
def HealthScreen(weight, height):
    bmi = round(weight/(float(height)*height),1)
    retv = "Your BMI is " +str(bmi)
    if bmi >= 25.5:
        retv += " (High Risk)."
    elif bmi >=23 and bmi <=27.4:
        retv += " (Moderate Risk)."
    elif bmi >= 18.5 and bmi <=22.9:
        retv += " (Low Risk)."
    elif bmi <18.5:
        retv += " (Risk of nutritional deficiency diseases)."
    return retv
```

I know the code isn't very pretty, but it went trough a lot of trial and error. I thought about adding code to check if either of the given numbers is zero, but still failed.

What am I not seeing?

Comment: One should not need to log into another site/service in order to read the question.

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot about that. It's fixed now though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if bmi >= 25.5:
    retv += " (High Risk)."
```

You specify >= 25.5 but in the instructions it specifies high risk is for a BMI over 27.5

Comment: Oh Jeez, I guess that's what happens when you stay up all night... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
if bmi >= 25.5:
```

Should be

```
if bmi >= 27.5:
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer:

```
def BMI(weight, height): 
BMI = round(weight/(float(height)*height),1)
return "%.1f" %BMI
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def HealthScreen(weight, height):
height=float(height)
bmi=weight/height**2
if bmi>=27.5:
    return 'Your BMI is %.1f (High Risk).' %bmi
elif 27.4>bmi>23:
    return 'Your BMI is %.1f (Moderate Risk).' %bmi
elif 22.9>bmi>18.5:
    return 'Your BMI is %.1f (Low Risk).' %bmi
else:
    return 'Your BMI is %.1f (Risk of nutritional deficiency diseases).' %bmi
```